# Can't use database connection while inside loop

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, connection

I am having a problem with mysqli. I am trying to search a database for all people who meet a category. While looping through the results, I want to create an instance of a "Person" class, passing the database connection to the class. This is where the problem starts. Here is my code.

```
$con = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die(mysqli_connect_error()); //There was an error. Print it out and die
}

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
if ($stmt)
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $person = new Person( $con );
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

If i move the `$person = new Person( $con );` to just after the while loop, it successfully makes an object of the last person.  It just won't work when inside the loop.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: Inside the loop you're continuosly overwriting $person

Comment: What do you mean under "it just won't work inside the loop"? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: The "person" object has lots of methods, many of which I will be calling during the loop process. On each iteration of the loop, it is true, $person will be overwritten. That is fine as I would have done everything I needed with the object by then. Ultimately, after each  of the $person methods have been called, the last method prints certain properties, such as as name, age etc.  It will form part of a UL list.

Comment: What i mean by "it wont work inside the loop" is the $con variable doesn't seem to be valid.  If I change the `$person = new Person( $con );` with `if($con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users")); {echo "yes";}else{echo "no";}` (not terrible efficient, but demonstrates that $con is still valid) the page repeatedly outputs 'no'.

Comment: Try to run `if($con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users")); {echo "yes";}else{echo $con->error; } ` instead of `$person = new Person($con)` and see what it tells

Comment: it says 'Command out of sync. You can't use this command now'

Comment: It looks like you are passing in the $con details which is an mysqli object, and thus passing an object to an object, would you not be better off declaring the params for the connection as an array which can then be fed into the person object as an array or individual array elements? This would offer you more drier and more versatile way of reusing these connection details. Unless you do infact want the whole connection object which offers other details that Im not aware of..

This might also be of use: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Hope thats of some help...

Comment: Yes, I could try that. I am only doing this way, because when I asked the best approach on this forum several months ago, i was advised that it would probably be better to pass the actual connection rather than connection details. I am unsure of the logic behind that, but I accepted it. I will try it your way and see how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error shown, you can't use the same connection until previous result set is in use.  In order to make it work, you can do something like this:

```
    $personIDs = array();
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $personIDs[] = $id;
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

and than just go through all ids buffered into array:

```
foreach($personIDs as $id) {
    $person = new Person( $con );
}
```

Or, you can use [store_results](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

```
if ($stmt)
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->store_results();

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $person = new Person( $con );
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```